# Truncate PyHandle (win32file)

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you truncate a PyHandle returned by win32file.CreateFile. I know you can open it with the TRUNCATE_EXISTING flag, but how do you truncate it to a specific size after reading/writing? Note: The reason I cannot use the standard library is because I'm using win32file to restrict simultaneous reading/writing to a file.

Comment: Does writing 0 bytes at the position you want the file to end work?

Comment: @cco I figured it out, calling win32file.SetEndOfFile(self._handle), seems to work. If you want to make that an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `win32file.SetEndOfFile(handle)` after positioning the file handle to the offset that you want to be the new end of file.  This is similar to the `ftruncate` POSIX system call, or writing 0 bytes in DOS.